# Delphi 10.4 - Define tfield size from RestRequest via RESTResponseDataSetAdapter

Tags: rest, delphi, adapter

I searched the Delphi help half a day but can't find any Solution to my problem.
There is a Delphi Client written as FMX form, but that should not be a problem here, same problem in vcl or terminal. I use the TRESTRequest -> RESTClient -> RESTResponse -> TRESTResponseDatasetAdapter -> tFdmemtable -> Livebinding -> tStringgrid construction. Everything works fine for getting the Data. But I would like to write some updates Back to that service and insert new Data.

On my form there is a SAVE button. When pressing that save button my plan is to write every new and updated Dataset, written in FDMEMtable back into Webservice.

At that Point I have a really annoying Problem.

The first RestRequest returns only one String, let's say "Hello" so the TrestResponseDatasetAdapter looks to this string and get's to the decision "Okay, it's a String with Size of 5". So far so good, but the Field itself in Rest Service can handle Strings of Size 50. So when I add new Row inside the Grid and Type a new value, the Grid would only save 5 digits because TrestResponseDatasetAdapter sets my tmemtable field to size 5.

I was trying to use Fielddefs from TrestResponseDatasetAdapter which works, but than I lose the possibility to load every new field dynamically. If it is not defined in TrestResponseDatasetAdapter it would not appear in Grid. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the value of MetaMergeMode? The default _Merge_ should allow field definitions and adding missing fields at the same time.

Comment: Hi Uwe, Thx for your comment. By the way, thank you for your Posts in german Delphi forums, that helped me a lot :)
MetaMergeMode is set to merge and was not changed.

Comment: Please try to provide a minimal sample showing the problem.

Comment: Okay, really Strange. I tryed to do a full demo project for that problem. But after creating every componentn it works as expected. I delete every componentn on my  Form and create it new on my own (not with restdebugger) now everything works fine..... Thank you for your Help.

Comment: This happens frequently. There is something else in your code which has a side effect and breaks the normal working. Now you just have to remove some features in your project until it works (The last thing will be what breaks it) or rebuild your project starting from the demo project until the bad behavior happens (And you'll know what break the thing).

Comment: I've just encountered the same problem with the RESTResponse / RestResponseDatasetAdapter.  The solution of defining the FieldDefs works, but seems overly complicated, especially if only a few fields are affected in a dataset with dozens of fields that work just fine.   Has anyone discovered a simple way to set a minimum string length ~just~ for the fields that need it?

Comment: Did you use RestDebugger Tool to create the Components?

Comment: No, I'm not able to use the RestDebugger -- it's possible a newer version of Delphi fixes the problem I had with RestDebugger -- it wouldn't work with a server that required bearer tokens.   But I came up with a solution that works for me -- I've predefined all the fields in a database table, so I simply copy all the fielddefs from the TFDTable to the RestResponseDatasetaAdapter.  No more truncated strings.

Comment: Unfortunately, bearer token will not work with RestDebugger, because every Time the Request is sent, the Connection will be created from Scratch, so the Request leaves its bearer tokens. Even in newer Versions, this still exists because it is more of a workflow Problem. Good to here, that you get your Problem fixed.